# How to remove or hide breadcrumbs for a particular page in magento

Tags: magento, hide, breadcrumbs

I am trying to hide the (Home > Catalog Advanced Search > Results) breadcrumbs alone in magento during the advanced search results. I don't want to navigate through the breadcrumbs in result page. Anybody help me to make this possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using

```
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
```

Within specific handle of your layout xml file. 
For example

```
<catalog_category_default>
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
</catalog_category_default>
```

Or try using that within the cms page layout form in backend under CMS->Pages.

Comment: @Harit, from backend CMS->Pages->Layout Update XML we can't write <remove> tag. It's allow only ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent )

Answer (score 4):

You can do by the admin:

```
CMS-> Pages:
Page Information
Design:
Custom Design
Custom Layout Update XML: <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 Code to remove breadcrumbs for CMS Page

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove breadcrumbs in various ways in Magento.

For example if you want remove from a specific action like (Home > Catalog Advanced Search > Results) you just update `catalogsearch_advanced_result` in catalogsearch.xml file from your theme with:

```
 <catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
     <remove name="breadcrumbs" />    
 </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

If you want to remove from all dynamic pages add this

```
 <default>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
 </default>
```

If you want to remove from a CMS page, you just configure from admin panel. Go to

```
system->configuration and then web->Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages.
```

Refresh your cache  and check.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.1

Goto Admin->Store->General->Web->Default Pages->Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages

Select Option No for breadcrumbs

Comment: Can also apply to Magento 1.9

Answer (score 1):

For Magento2 Remove from specific CMS page. Add following on Design >>Layout section of you CMS page

```
  <referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
  </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit catalogsearch.xml in /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/

Add `<remove name="breadcrumbs" />` within

```
  <catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
   <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
   <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
  </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Refresh and check... Breadcrumbs will be removed in advanced search result alone.

Comment: Your answer is right. But it's never a good practice to hack the code inside  /app/design/frontend/base/ directory. 
Magento allows you to override that file to app/design/frontend/default so override catalogsearch.xml to /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/ or your theme folder and do modifications to it. Also an alternative way is to create a local.xml file in your theme folder. Check this link for better understanding http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: I will proceed as you suggested... Thankyou Harit

Answer (score 0):

In layout update xml, per cms page:

```
<reference name="root">
<remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</reference>
```